# How can I use my Android Phones to remember more than 200 Paired Bluetooth devices?

Tags: bluetooth, 9.0-pie, 8.0-oreo, bluetooth-pairing

- My In house app communicates with Bluetooth device (In house) via an Android Phone;
- I require a device (Android) to store pairing information for more than 200 devices (Bluetooth);
- Currently, I am losing the pairing information in my devices (Android) after more than 100 devices are paired;

  - The paired device name is not lost, but it asks for re-pairing;
  - If I cancel the pairing request, the Bluetooth device un–pairs with Android (device);
- I have conducted the same test with various Android devices and the same issue happens;
- I have googled various forums and observed that there is practically no limit for Bluetooth devices to be paired;
- I need your help to solve the issue so that my device can remember pairing information for more than 200 devices;
- Currently used phones are Xiaomi Redmi 7 (Pie) and Samsung A7 (Oreo).

Comment: If you are getting the same result from various devices then the Bluetooth link key cache size and the Bluetooth device description cache size this is most likely an integral part of  Bluedroid stack. Changing those values would require to identify the relevant parts in the C source code, increase the values and compile it. If you manage to get exact the version used on your device you may be able to replace the Bluedroid stack with your self-compiled version. Otherwise you would have to build a complete custom ROM.